# How to have document based authorization in Elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to build a query in Elasticsearch that would only search documents with a certain custom ID. A *User* has many *Opportunities* and an *Opportunity* has many *Tasks*.

On the *Opportunity*, the primary key is **labs_id__c**
On the *Task*, the foreign key for an Opportunity is **opportunity_id__c**

I would like to build a query that only searches objects that have reference to Opportunity foreign key. The purpose of this, is to only allow Users to search for related Tasks or related objects within their own *Opportunities*.

How do I do this?

Comment: Your use case doesn't seem to need elasticsearch. Maybe consider using sql instead?

Comment: There are several other related objects that I would be searching for which I did not mention. Furthermore, I would be searching for terms within various fields, not just within Tasks.

Comment: Check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/mapping-parent-field.html for one to many

Comment: FYI I'm searching across multiple models as well.

Comment: For your use case (what you described at least, in your post) imho is covered by the link I shared. If you have a far more complicated problem, then you need to elaborate more in your initial post and give some initial work and sample data, otherwise it will be very difficult if not impossible to receive assistance here

Comment: What does your mapping look like?